# How can I improve the way I'm managing my secret API keys for my NodeJS app that's hosted on Heroku

Tags: node.js, security, heroku, environment-variables, secret-key

I've created a .env file per the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) documentation and placed all my secret API keys inside the file. I've also added these environment variables as config variables to my Heroku instance. As a result, secret API strings are no longer referenced in my source code.

However, I haven't gitignored the .env file since the git repo is set to private and I'm the sole owner of it but I have slugignored the .env file to stop it from being pushed into Heroku.

Is my justification to not gitignore the .env file safe and are the steps I'm taking reasonable and standard practice to protect my secret API strings? If not, how else can I improve upon my setup to improve the security of my web app?

Answer (score 0):

Are the creds in `.env` the same ones you have on your heroku app?
If so, this is bad.

Someone getting access to your GitHub account could also access the creds in your Heroku app. Look at this [Gentoo retrospective](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Github/2018-06-28) where getting their GitHub organization compromised is exactly what happened.

Your `.env` file should only have local settings. For example, it should call `localhost` as the database, not your production database URL.

Then, once everything is decoupled from production, this file can safely be checked into your repository. Someone getting access to your code wouldn't be getting any access to your production data.

Comment: Oh wow....I just read your link to Gentoo and it seems like my trust in storing my .env file on Github is misplaced. In that case, how do people work collaboratively on projects while ensuring that everyone has the correct API keys? Is the file shared separately (through some other secure means) and always kept away from the central repository? And yes, some of the keys are the same ones on the heroku app.

Comment: Locally, you should never use production API keys. If you need OAuth credentials for a third-party app for example, the developer should create their own development OAuth app and configure it locally.

Comment: I see. Would you mind clarifying what an OAuth app is? I tried looking around online and stumbled upon [this](https://developer.github.com/apps/differences-between-apps/#who-can-install-github-apps-and-authorize-oauth-apps) but it wasn't entirely helpful in clarifying what an OAuth app actually is, just that it is different from your standard Github app (I hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree).